# Python Tkinter delete title bar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, title

I'm looking for very long time for a solution for this. I want to delete the Titlebar of a Tk window, like with the function "overridedirect()". My problem with that function is, that there is no icon on the taskbar of the OS.
I also tried it with "root.attributes("-fullscreen",  1)" and tried to scale it down, but that doesn't work either.
I hope somebody knows a good solution, thanks for help!

My code looks kind of like this now:

```
from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
**...**
#There are more classes after this one, but defined the same way

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x400+0+0")
    root.minsize(700, 400)
    root.title("Title")
    #root.overrideredirect(True)
    #root.iconify()
    ##root.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    ##root.attributes("-fullscreen",  1)
    ##root.wm_state("zoomed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. You can either have no titlebar and no icon, or you can have a titlebar and icon. There is no way to get one without the other.